# Need a simple wifi connection monitor

Tags: wireless

I've been using Ubuntu for a while now and have some Unix experience going back to '86. I recently converted my mom's desktop to Ubuntu but could use a simple desktop wifi status/monitor. She lives in an assisted living community, I need to easily be able to see when the wifi is live/dead, if internet is live/dead, to help easily figure out if she has done something I have to fix or if it is a service issue. I've looked at similar questions posted here, nothing seems appropriate.

Comment: Android phone? -> https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.farproc.wifi.analyzer

Comment: I've written a bash script to help with this: `https://github.com/waltinator/net-o-matic` It watches the connection, and when the connection drops, does a user-specified thing to try to reconnect or do something else.

Comment: If you (the system administrator) does not give mom (the user) `sudo` access the harm she can do is reduced.